# Splitting of Algebra Acting on a Module?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional commutative unital algebra over $\mathbb{K}$ (of most interest to me in $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$). Let $V$ be a finitely generated $A$-module and let $m:A\otimes_{\mathbb{K}} V\rightarrow V$ be the action of $A$ on $V$.

Then we have an exact sequence of $A$-modules $0\rightarrow ker(m)\rightarrow A\otimes_{\mathbb{K}} V\rightarrow V\rightarrow 0$ given by inclusion and then $m$.

Does this sequence always split (i.e is $A\otimes_{\mathbb{K}} V\cong ker(m)\oplus V$ canonically)?

Comment: I'm sure you do, but to be clear: You mean 1) $A$ to act on $A\otimes V$ on the first factor (and therefore so that $A\otimes V \simeq A^n$ as $A$-modules, where $n$ is the dimension of $V$ over $\mathbb K$ )? 2) by split, you mean as $A$-modules?

Comment: please reload my previous - typo!

Comment: yep 1) and 2) are both what I meant!

Answer (score 3):

No.

Example: $A= k[\epsilon]$, with defining relation $\epsilon^2=0$, and $V=A/(\epsilon)\simeq k$, so that  $\epsilon \cdot 1 =0$.
Then the exact sequence of $A$-modules
$$ 0 \to (\epsilon) \to A \to V \to 0$$
does not split because $\epsilon$ acts trivially on the kernel and cokernel. (Here $A\otimes_k V \simeq A$ as $A$-modules.)